# Can I mount a TV on a single metal stud?

Tags: drywall, walls, steel, television, mount

I'm finding a lot of conflicting info on this.

I have a 53.1 lbs TV (65") that I want to mount using a flush mount (5.9lbs) to my wall. However the studs (24" apart) are off center so I would be looking to mount it on the center stud.

I live in a building that's about 12 years old, so modern construction. I've seen advice from "yes, snap toggles on the stud and anchors on drywall will do" to "you need a piece of plywood across 3 studs and then you can center your mount"... (as for that last one, the rightmost stud has electrical running through it so it complicates things even more!)

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the mount itself and the size of anchors. Two 1/4 inch lag bolts into a stud can hold hundreds of pounds but if the mount has a long arm the amount of weight is reduced because of the length away from the wall.

The framework may not be able to handle the weight with only one side supported securely. A thick piece of plywood anchored to the stud with lag bolts and fender washers (washers reduce the chance of an over-tightened lag bolt pulling through the plywood) cut to the size of the bracket could carry the load, then attach the monitor frame to the plywood. Using this method, I would use 3/4" plywood and it would be able to handle the load.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! The wall mount is "low profile", so no arm extension/swivel. Here is the link:

https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00UNR0OOW/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I believe, based on what you said that mounting it on the stud with lag bolts will hold, but I can mount it with plywood to make sure it carries the load? Would I mount the plywood (cut to the size of the mount) on the single stud, or were you referring to a large piece of plywood mounted on 2 studs?

Comment: Just 1 stud with the plywood the same size as the bracket.

Comment: Don't understand how the weight would be reduced on a long-arm bracket... the weight will stay the same but the leverage trying to tear the top screws and bracket out of the wall will be increased by a long arm bracket.

Comment: The plywood provides the mounting surface for the bracket, if mounted on top of sheetrock the weight can cause the sheetrock to break up but by using plywood to spread the load this will keep the damage to the sheetrock from breaking,  larger lag bolts holding the plywood in place will support hundreds of lbs, this is how I supported CRT displays with double arms and they are moved and adjusted all the time. By double arm I am talking about a jointed arm that was 18-24" long. Prior to adding the plywood the side force when adjusting would crack the sheetrock with just the mount.

Answer (score 0):

Though, you mentioned this, I ran into a similar situation and here is what I did. I took a piece of 3/4 plywood long enough to stretch between studs. I like to over engineer so I don't need to worry. Secured it to the studs with 4 3" lag screws. You don't need to go to all 3 studs so the one with electric can be left alone, though, you can probably space the lag screws where the wire isn't. 2 studs is sufficient. I then connected the mount to the plywood. It's been like this for over 2 yrs with a similar size tv without issue even with the arm fully stretched out. If you spend the time on the plywood/solid wood you can get it to look like like it's part of the wall or you could go for a really large sheets from floor to ceiling. I've seen some like this that get a nice stain and they look really nice.